About multiplicative properties of rounding down
everyone .
I'm now working on a formal proof for falcon, which has an algorithm called ApproxExp, whose purpose is to give an approximation to exp(-x)* ccs* 2^63, An important idea of his algorithm is that floor(floor(2^63*x) *C /2^63) should be approximately floor(x * C). C is a large integer(such as 19127174051), and after 8 or 9 applications, there will be a large error. This error will be accumulated.I think it is necessary to analyze the error margin of floor(a) * floor(b) to help me estimate the error margin of the algorithm.
How should we prove that $$(a-1) * (b-1) < \left \lfloor a \right \rfloor *\left \lfloor b \right \rfloor  $$
Is there any condition for this to work?

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The floor function reduces a number by less than 1.
let $x = \lfloor y \rfloor$, maximum value of $y$, s.t. $\lfloor y \rfloor$ is $x$, is $x + 1 - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the smallest nonnegative real number. since $1 - \epsilon$ is less then 1, when we floor $y$, it's value is reduced by less than one, so $a - 1 \lt \lfloor a \rfloor$ and the same holds for $b$. so $(a - 1) \cdot (b - 1) \lt \lfloor a \rfloor \cdot \lfloor b \rfloor$.
